# Fill the segment with circles

Tags: geometry, optimization, algorithms, dynamic-programming

There is a line. On this line, we have $N \le 100$ points $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$, $0 \le x_i \le 10^8$ which are centers of circles. We want to choose such radii for those circles, but in such way that they can't intersect (but they can be tangent). There is one more condition. We want those circles to have the highest possible sum of circumferences. We can write this sum as $2\pi r_1 + 2\pi r_2 + \cdots + 2\pi r_n$, where $r_i$ is radius of circle with center $x_i$. Taking $2\pi$, the task boils down to maximize $r_1 + r_2 + \cdots + r_n$, but with condition that those circles can't intersect. Also, any circle can't be inside any other. You can assume that centers are integers, but radii don't have to be integers. Also, every radius has to be positive (can't be equal to 0).

What is the fastest way to solve this? I would like to design an algorithm which could solve this.

Comment: Can you just throw a linear-programming solver at it?

Comment: Can you explain what is linear-programming? I never heard of it.

Comment: [Linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming). But that's probably overkill here, since I just now notice that all the points are on a line, rather than in a plane.

Comment: Yes, you can think of this line as if it was in 1D.

Comment: Are all of the points integers? Can you have some of the circles inside each other?

Comment: One circle can't be inside any other. All of the points are integers, but radiuses don't necessarily have to be integers.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Assume without loss of generality that $x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n$, and define the functions $f_i$ as
$$ f_i(d) = \text{the largest value of }\sum_{j\le i}r_j\text{ under the additional restriction that }r_i\le d $$
Then each $f_i$ will be a piecewise linear function of a particularly simple shape, and it is easy enough to derive $f_{i+1}$ given $f_{i}$ and the distance $x_{i+1}-x_j$.

Compute them all in sequence, and your answer will be the maximum of $f_n$.

---

(Actually, a bit of additional thought about the shape of the $f_i$s will reveal that the straightforward *greedy algorithm* is in fact optimal).

Comment: Could you write it in some simpler way? I am not very familiar with linear-programming and geometrical/analytical ways of solving problems.

Comment: This is not a _linear programming_ solution but a _dynamic programming_ one. Have you tried sketching the $f_i$s for a few concrete examplkes with small $n$?

Comment: After some time of thinking, I can't get to the solution.

Comment: @user4201961: Have you tried sketching the $f_i$s for a few concrete examples with small $n$?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a clever way to do the problem: First suppose there are only two circles. It is not hard to show the sum of the circumferences is independent of how we choose the radii, provided they are tangent.

Thus $C_1+C_2$ is independent of the arrangement. Likewise for $C_2 + C_3$ and $C_3 + C_4$ and so on. We conclude that $C_1 + 2C_2 + +2C_3 + \ldots + 2C_{98} + 2C_{99} + C_{100}$ is independent.

Now maximizing  $C_1 + C_2  + \ldots  + C_{99} + C_{100}$ is the same as maximizing $2C_1 + 2C_2  + \ldots  + 2C_{99} + 2C_{100}$. By the above logic this is equivalent to maximising $C_1 + C_{100}$.

**Edit:** This only works if the maximum can be achieved by all circles being tangent. It may not help when there are an even number of points. In that case maximizing the first and last radius will prevent some circle in the middle having nonzero radius.

Comment: Clever solution, indeed !  Little remark: I think the term "independent" in what "We conclude that  $C_1+2C_2+2C_3+…+2C_{98}+2C_{99}+C_{100}$ IS INDEPENDENT", could be replace by "constant".

Comment: But it's not always _possible_ for all the circles to be tangent. Consider for example $\{1,2,5,6,7,10,11\}$.